# Variable shape tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow

I need to get a tensor that is variable shape as I do not know the vector size before hand. So far I tried:

```
hashtag_len = tf.placeholder(tf.int32)
train_hashtag = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[hashtag_len])
```

but I get the error `TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'Tensor'`.

The only other way around this that I can think of is to pad the vector with enough zeros so that I can fit the intended vector inside a giant vector. Seems like tensorflow should have a better way of doing this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a VECTOR for sure, you should do the following:

```
train_hashtag = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[None])
```

This shape describes vector of arbitrary length.

Answer (score 2):

Use

`tf.placeholder(tf.int32)`

That creates placeholder of arbitrary shape